# Rails 3 how to deal with constants

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, constants, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a constant called `PAYMENT_METHODS` in `venue.rb`.

```
PAYMENT_METHODS = ['Visa', 'MasterCard', 'American Express', 'Diners', 'JCB', 'Bankomat', 'sodexo', 'MA-Gutscheine']
```

You can check/uncheck the payment types in a form (`payment_options` is an integer):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "venue[payment_options][]", nil %>
<% Venue::PAYMENT_METHODS.each do |category| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "venue[payment_options][]", category %>
  <%= label_tag category %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to save the selection, but the value of each check box is the name of the payment option. I think I have to somehow add a key an store only the keys.

How do I set keys and save the collection to the database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would you like the values to be instead?

Comment: Thought of integers (1,2,3...) and only store them to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the constant a hash or an array, e.g.

```
PAYMENT_METHODS = {'Visa' => 1, 'MasterCard' => 2, 'American Express' => 3, 'Diners' => 4, 'JCB' => 5, 'Bankomat' => 6, 'sodexo' => 7, 'MA-Gutscheine' => 8 }
```

These will now be in a format that you can pass to `options_for_select` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select.

If you (really) want checkboxes, an array is fine, just loop over using `PAYMENT_MTHODS.each_index do |index|` to get an iterator that's the value, and then use `PAYMENT_METHODS[index]`.

I have always found it odd that the hash *key* is the part displayed in the list, but I guess it makes sense that the value is what is associated with the option's value :-).

Comment: thx, works great on a select tag. But I need a solution where people can check multiple payment options.

Comment: I realized this was your question and added a method for doing checkboxes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Save the string value itself nothing wrong with that.

Its better to create a model like `PaymentType` and just keep `id,name` and in view render all payment types.This way you can better manipulate all available payment options in future from an admin panel (if needed) rather than going to a code level and changing at the constant.

Comment: thx, thought about that too, but that would mean one more table in the db hence more traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an element's index as a key. Use `Array#index` to your advantage.

```
PAYMENT_METHODS.index("Visa")   #=> 0
PAYMENT_METHODS[0]              #=> "Visa"

PAYMENT_METHODS.index("Diners") #=> 3
PAYMENT_METHODS[3]              #=> "Diners"
```

A word of caution: This will break if you reorder `PAYMENT_METHODS`. You are keying an element to it's relative position in the array. Change the array and you change the keys. Avoid trouble by keeping your constants **constant**.

Comment: You can also add virtual attributes to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to

> I have always found it odd that the hash key is the part displayed in the list, but I guess it makes sense that the value is what is associated with the option's value :-).

you can get that done by (it was bugging me a bit as well)

```
<% Post::TECH_CATEGORY.each do |category| %>
  <%= label_tag 'name', category[0] %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'tech_cat', category[1] %>
<% end %>
```

It makes sense now that I can see it on the screen. Each object has two values, so...

```
category[0]
```

will always be the key you supplied for that specific object you are currently enumerating over

```
category[1]
```

will be the value of that same object. Looks way better on the screen.

which looks like in your example above

```
<label for="name"> Visa </label>
<input id="tech_cat" name="tech_cat" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Cheers,